# Using pi in an URDF file

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We want to use the value of pi in an URDF file, since we have to rotate a model by 90 degrees. Is there any builtin macro for pi in URDF? At the moment we are simply using our own M_PI macro, but it would be nice to know what the intended way of doing such a thing would be.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277011/using-pi-in-an-urdf-file/) by [MatthiasLoebach](https://answers.ros.org/users/32823/matthiasloebach/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do this with **xacro** (a XML macro language): http://wiki.ros.org/xacro

From section *3. Math Expression*

> Since ROS Jade, Xacro employs python to evaluate expressions
> enclosed in dollared-braces (${}).
> > This allows for more complex
> > arithmetic expressions. Also, **some
> > basic constants, e.g. pi, are already
> > predefined**:
> > 
> >     <xacro:property name="R" value="2" />
> >     <xacro:property name="alpha" value="${30/180*pi}" />

---

You might be interested in the [ROS xacro tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File)

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8